# Are there any exotic examples of series expansions?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, fourier-series

The idea of a series expansion of a function is to express the function as an infinite series of simpler terms, which follow a pattern. Truncating such an expansion allows us to approximate the function.

Depending on the subsequent goal of the expansion (e.g. finding the limit of a quotient of functions, or performing frequency analysis), we usually have to choose two things: the form that the terms of the expansion take, and desired properties of the truncated approximation, the latter almost always being a property which expresses some notion of "closeness" between the approximation and the function.

What are probably the two most common examples of series expansions illustrate this quite well.

To find the limit of a function at a point, we mainly need our approximation to be locally close to the function being approximated. To do so, we can attempt to match their derivatives at that point up to a certain order. This is exactly what the Taylor expansion does, which is why we use it to compute limits. On top of that, the terms of the Taylor series are powers, making it a power series, which is nice.

To perform frequency analysis on a signal, we mainly need our approximation to have terms which depend on multiples of a frequency. This is exactly what the Fourier expansion does, which is why we use it for frequency analysis. Unlike in the previous example, we don't mind large local deviations, but do however mind large global deviations. To compute the Fourier expansion, then, we consider the terms to be a basis of sinusoids and project the function on that basis.

This leads me to my two questions related to series expansions:

1. Are there any expansions which use terms which aren't powers or sinusoids?
2. Are there any expansions where the coefficients of the terms aren't computed to obtain a locally close or globally close approximation, but rather another desirable property of the approximation?

Comment: Does, for example, wavelet expansion or Hermite expansion count?

Comment: Wavelet expansion certainly counts for question 1, as the terms are wavelets (strictly speaking, not sinusoids). The Hermite expansion is a polynomial expansion, if you cited it for question 2, what desirable property must its truncation/approximation fulfill and how does it then determine the coefficients of the terms?

Comment: With respect to the first question are you aware of the Fourier Bessel series (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier%E2%80%93Bessel_series and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fourier-BesselSeries.html)?

Comment: With respect to the first question one of my favorites is $H_x=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ where $H_x$ is the analytic Harmonic number function, $f(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}$, and Moebius inversion leads to $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n} H_{\frac{x}{n}}$.

Comment: With respect to question (1) Dirichlet series such as $\zeta(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s},\ \Re(s)>1$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletL-Series.html) and Modular forms (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModularForm.html) are perhaps some of the most important.